# Instantiating objects in initComponent to be used in items

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I keep coming across this problem. I have a custom component with 'items' defined. I want someone to use my component but define some configuration values, (ie I want a constructor for my widget!).

Lets say I have a component like this. I want an argument passed through 'someArgumentPassedInAsConfig', and i want this set on some items object in the items tree.

```
Ext.define('MySuperDupeyComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    alias: 'widget.MySuperDupeyComponent',

    initComponent: function() {
        alert('ch --> ' + this.someArgumentPassedInAsConfig);
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'someWidget',
        somePropertyIwantToSet: this.someArgumentPassedInAsConfig
    }]
})
```

What is the best way to do this? I want someone to be able to use my component like this.

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'MySuperDupeyComponent',
        someArgumentPassedInAsConfig: 'Blah blah blah'
    }
```

Is the only way to use Ext.apply in the constructor?

Comment: I had a funny feeling that I asked this question years ago. Seems like I did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945173/declaring-default-values-in-config/37946226#37946226

Answer (score 3):

Declaring the items inside the initComponent method should work, if this is what you're looking for.

```
Ext.define('MySuperDupeyComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    alias: 'widget.MySuperDupeyComponent',

    initComponent: function() {
        alert('ch --> ' + this.someArgumentPassedInAsConfig);
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'someWidget',
            somePropertyIwantToSet: this.someArgumentPassedInAsConfig
        }]
        this.callParents(arguments);
    }
})
```

Should allow you to use it like this

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'MySuperDupeyComponent',
        someArgumentPassedInAsConfig: 'Blah...'
    }]
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/1i07